# Is there any restriction/limit to number of advertisements we can put in android app?

Tags: android, ads, policy, google-play

I have developed an android app that is ready for upload on play store. There is a lot of free space in the app where I would like to put ads.

Does anyone know if there are any kind of restrictions on putting lots of ads in android app(particularly in goolge play store)?

Comment: most of developers put 2 to 3 types of ads in one screen. As i know google don't have any problem with number of ads you put in screen but it is good, if you do not put too much Ads as user will be irritated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The number of ads on a single screen should not exceed one if the ad
>   is fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, only
>   one ad should be visible on the screen at a time, and, according to
>   the AdSense program policies, publishers may place no more than 3 ad
>   units on one entire page.

Reference: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en

> Ads associated with your app must not interfere with other apps or their ads. This includes overlays, companion functionality, or widgetized ad units.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2986118?hl=en